# Oracle : Autopopulate foreign key if parent table referenced column has values

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, foreign-keys

This could be dumb question but somehow I am not able to get around it.

I have the tables `status` and `logs`, both tables have `jobId` column. `jobId` is generated based on sequence and so I want to add `sequence generated jobId` from `logs` table to `status` page.

I have created foreign key in `status` table referencing to `jobId` column to `logs` table but jobId values are not populated in `status` table.

How can I autopopulate `jobId` in `status` table when `jobId` is auto-generated in `logs` using sequence?

**Update**

```
<id name="jobid"
        column="JOBID"
        type="long"
        unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">ID_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Here is how am generating id for `status` page, as suggested i need to use ID_SEQ.curval but how can i do that in hibernate, any idea?

something like

```
<id name="id"
        column="ID"
        type="long"
        unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">ID_SEQ.curval</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are using the sequence to populate this column but most likely you want to use the `currval` of the sequence when you are populating the `jobID` in the `status` table.

In the simplest case, you have two tables and a sequence

```
SQL> create table logs(
  2    jobID number primary key
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> create table status (
  2    jobID number references logs(jobID)
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence jobID_seq;

Sequence created.
```

When you insert into `logs`, you use the `nextval` of the sequence and when you insert into `status` you use the `currval` of the sequence.  `currval` gives you the most recent value for your session so there is no risk that you'll see a `currval` that was given to some other session

```
SQL> insert into logs values( jobID_seq.nextval );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into status values( jobID_seq.currval );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from logs;

     JOBID
----------
         5

SQL> select * from status;

     JOBID
----------
         5
```

If you are using triggers (I'm using the 11g syntax here-- you can use the old `SELECT jobID_seq.nextval into :new.jobID from dual` syntax if you're on an older version)

```
SQL> create trigger trg_logs
  2    before insert on logs
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.jobID := jobID_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create trigger trg_status
  2    before insert on status
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.jobID := jobID_seq.currval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

I'm not quite sure, though, that it really makes sense to try to automatically populate a foreign key like this.  Presumably, there are cases where you will be adding rows to the child table for a parent row that you didn't just insert, for example.  Perhaps you can work around that by adding an `IF` condition to the trigger on the `status` table that checks to see if a non-NULL value has been provided already

```
create trigger trg_status
  before insert on status
  for each row
begin
  if( :new.jobID IS NULL )
  then
    :new.jobID := jobID_seq.currval;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for detail answer, my understanding was that foreign keys are autopopulated based on entries in parent column but that is not happening and also i do not find a way of entering values in foreign key.

Comment: @Rachel = By default, no, foreign keys are not automatically populated.  Generally, you have to supply the value when you are doing the `INSERT`.  Frequently, you would use the `currval` of the sequence explicitly if you know that you want to use the `jobID` for the most recently inserted row in `logs`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to do that using hibernate?

Comment: @Rachel - Not off the top of my head.  Added a Hibernate tag so hopefully we'll draw some Hibernate experts.  If you want to do that automatically, and assuming that you would never create a child row without creating the parent row earlier in the same session (which would be odd but not impossible), you could define one of the triggers I posted and just insert a NULL from Hibernate

Comment: Thanks for your input, let me give it a try and see if that hits the target, much thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `currval` after you inserted the the rows in the logs table:

```
insert into logs (jobid) values (seq_jobid.nextval);
insert into status (jobid) values (seq_jobid.currval);
```